# How to improve on the preferred regression model?

Tags: regression, self-study, multicollinearity, structural-change, chow-test

[image]

After running the chow test, the F stat shows structural change is present in the model, so the unrestricted models are preferred. I am not sure how I can choose from the two regression models in the picture but I understand they are preferred over the restricted model as H0 is rejected.

The final part of the question asks [image]

I am thinking about multicollinearity and using IVF to test for it. Since they have already included the lagged variable; I am just guessing the inclusion of dummy variable is also required to test for seasonal variation. What more can I add here?  I am not sure if it is okay to mention to increase of sample size so that the estimation of sample can be closer to the true population.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the self-study tag and considering removing the "leas-squares" tag, since this is a homework question.

Comment: I have just made some changes, thanks.

Comment: If I was choosing between two models and I had no theoretical basis to do so, I would want to know which predicted better a hold out data set (you exclude part of the data, estimate the model then predict the hold out data). Chow tests usually are testing the theory that the regression model's parameters are not the same in one period as another, but I don't understand the comments made well enough to be sure that is what you are doing. If the parameters are different in different periods you want to run separate models not one model for the entire data set. Test for autocorrelation.